# Different configuration values during development and production on Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application that communicates with a server. When I am developing I want the app to use one server and port and when deploying it in production I want it to use a different server and port.

I thought that I could perhaps store the server name and port as a string resource and then override these values during development. But that does not seem to be possible since there is no quantifier for development.

What is the common way to provide different values to an App during development and production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardcore way, use Ant, or better yet, AndroidAnt, which you can configure builds by simply calling different command line options,

http://code.google.com/p/autoandroid/wiki/AndroidAnt

Comment: I had hope there was a built-in way to do it, but thanks for the answer anyway.